# Angular - Unit testing focusing on button

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, karma-runner

I am attempting to unit test whether my button has been focused on, but I cannot seem to get the spy to work correctly?

I saw [this post][1], but it hasn't helped fully.

Am I missing something obvious?

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    // autofocus on the cancel button to guard against mistakes
    document.getElementById('cancel').focus();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focus is flawed to start with.

When using Angular, you should not use `document` to fetch your elements.

Use a viewChild instead.

```
@ViewChild('cancel') cancelButton: ElementRef<HtmlButtonElement>;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.cancelButton.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Now your test looks like this

```
it('should focus cancel button', () => {
  spyOn(component.cancelButton.nativeElement, 'focus');
  component.ngAfterViewInit();
  expect(component.cancelButton.nativeElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
});
```

**EDIT** If you still want to use your way, consider using [`By.css()`](https://angular.io/guide/testing#bycss) :

```
it('should autofocus on cancel button on init', () => {
  const cancelButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#cancel'));
  spyOn(cancelButton, 'focus');
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(cancelButton.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Yes, take advantage of `fixture` instead of relying on `document` to get html elements.

Comment: @trichetriche - I implemented the `@ViewChild` but it is saying that it can't find name 'cancelButton'?

Comment: is your button something like `<button #cancel>Cancel</button>` ? You need to give it a template variable reference with `#cancel`

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that after googling. It also appears that you don't need the first colon ':' after `('cancel') :`? And it should be HTML not Html in `HtmlButtonElement` :-)

Comment: @physicsboy woops, TY for the typo ! Also, `ElementRef<HtmlButtonElement>` is used to type your element : when you write `this.cancelButton.nativeElement`, if you append a dot, you will have intellisense for an HTML button element. Not mandatory, but practical !

Answer (score 2):

Recall `ngOnInit()` after your `spy` has been created in your spec, as pointed by @trichietrichie

Also, take advantage of `fixture` instead of relying on `document` to fetch html elements.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ConfirmationComponent ],
      providers: [ MessageService]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfirmationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();    
    component.ngOnInit();
  });

  it('should autofocus on cancel button on init', () => {
    const cancelButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#cancel'));
    spyOn(cancelButton.nativeElement, 'focus'); // create spy here   
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(cancelButton.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: or recall `ngOnInit` so you don't create `[it.count]` times a spy that you use once ?

Comment: Hmm, I see the issue, so he has to postpone the `ngOnInit()` invokation.

Comment: Yes & no : `ngOnInit` will be called at every component instanciation (which is at every `it` since we create it in a `beforeEach`) : but `ngOnInit` being just a specifically named function, you can just call it a second time, this time with a spy so that you can monitor it. So not really postponed, but recalled.

Comment: Recall `ngOnInit()`? Okay. Should not be an issue for testing.

Comment: Even in the component, recalling it won't be an issue ... As said, `ngOnInit` is ismply a function. The fact that it's called by Angular itself isn't dangerous or anything !

Comment: Well, it is not an issue. But we would be misusing it, if we do so.

Comment: Again, no ! lifecycle hooks are here to ensure you can have access to specific elements (for instance, you won't get `ViewContainerRef` in `ngOnInit`, but you will in `ngAfterViewInit`). Hooks are just functions called by Angular. For instance, I implemented something similar with a decorator, that is getting trigerred by events. The functions ran are called `ngOnCustomEvent(eventType: string)` : nothing prevents me from running them when I want, but I know for a fact that they will be ran when a custom event occurs, without me having to call them by hand.

Comment: Not until you remove the use of `document` ;)

Comment: Even better than removing the downvote ! Fully valid answers deserve upvotes :)